# How to access Build properties on waterfall page inside buildbot stages?

Tags: buildbot

How can I access the build properties like `event.change.id` etc that are displayed on buildbot waterfall page, inside one of the buildbot stages, `cbuildbot_stages.py`?

-Pratibha

Answer (score 2):

Buildbot offers a mechanism to access those properties.  It is described in http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/cfg-properties.html#using-properties-in-steps

You will need to use `Interpolate` class to get the value that you are looking for: for example, `Interpolate('%(prop:event.change.id)s`.

Please note the introduction section that describes possible mistakes people make when they start using this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

What and where is this file `cbuildbot_stages.py` ?

You could override the default buildbot behavior with what you want in your buildbot config file. Standard OOP practice.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am using buildbot to build chromium os. cbuildbot_stages.py script is in /chromite/buildbot/ directory.

I want to access the gerrit change id in buildbot stages.